# python tsne.transform does not exist?

Tags: python, tsne

I am trying to transform two datasets: x_train and x_test using tsne. I assume the way to do this is to fit tsne to x_train, and then transform x_test and x_train. But, I am not able to transform any of the datasets.

`tsne = TSNE(random_state = 420, n_components=2, verbose=1, perplexity=5, n_iter=350).fit(x_train)`

I assume that tsne has been fitted to x_train.

But, when I do this:

`x_train_tse = tsne.transform(x_subset)`

I get:

`AttributeError: 'TSNE' object has no attribute 'transform'`

Any help will be appreciated. (I know I could do `fit_transform`, but wouldn't I get the same error on x_test?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a particular peculiarity of TSNE in sklearn:  https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5361

Comment: Huh, what is even the point of tsne then? It onnly shows that my data can be neatly reduced to 2 dimensions?

Comment: @NoLand'sMan Yes, for now it seems to primarily be a visualization helper.  As discussed in the linked issue, there may be a way to use it as a complete transformer, but it has not yet been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The TSNE algorithm doesn't learn a transformation function, it directly optimizes the positions of the lower-dimensional points, therefore the idea of `.transform()` does not apply to TSNE. One option is to embed a bunch of data via TSNE then use some type of supervised regression (linear regression, for example) to approximate the transformation in order to apply to future data.